# Scheduled Lambda function not able to make 3rd party API calls

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I've got 3 functions.

1. Cron job lambda function
2. Event driven function which detects when a new record is added to the DynamoDB
3. A reusable function which is currently called by the 2 above functions

The Cron job function

```
export async function scheduledFunction() {
    const detailsHistory = await sharedFunction(param1);
}
```

The event driven function

```
export async function eventFunction(event) {
    event.Records.forEach(async record => {
        if (record.eventName === 'INSERT') {
            await sharedFunction(param1)
        }
    }
}
```

The function called by both of the event and scheduled function

```
const sharedFunction = async (param1) {
    const apiUrl = 'xxxxxx';
    const details = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': xxxx
        }
    }); 
}
```

The event function works when the `DynamoDB` has a new insert and then calls the 3rd party API which works as expected

The scheduled function fires every 4 hours and is works and gets to the sharedFunction, but when its gets to the API call `await axios.get` it just does nothing, I'm not getting any errors in the `CloudWatch`. I've placed `console.logs()` before and after the call and it logs the one before but nothing after.

Answer (score 0):

You should always put async code inside `try ... catch` block. Also `forEach` won't work with promise you will need to use `for` loop. Try this:

```
export async function eventFunction(event) {
  try {

    for (let record of event.Records) {
      if (record.eventName === 'INSERT') {    
        await sharedFunction(param1)
      }
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
}
```

Shared function:

```
const sharedFunction = async (param1) => {
  try {
    const apiUrl = 'xxxxxx';
    return await axios.get(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': xxxx
        }
    });

  }
  catch (err) {
    return err;   
  } 
}
```